# Graph isomorphism on smaller graphs but large number of tests

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Graph isomorphism is a well studied problem in computer science but there are no polynomial time algorithms known(there are some claims but none of them have been proven yet).

I have to test isomorphism of two graph but for my case the problem is slightly different. The size of the graph is less than, say 10 or 11, that is less number of vertices. There is no bound on the number of edges that is graph can be dense or sparse. The number of such pairwise testing(isomorphism checks) will be around 10^8.

If someone could suggest a few algorithms which are best suited for such a case. Also it would be great if algorithm can be parallelized.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "The size of the graph is less than, say 10 or 11, that is less number of vertices" does not quite make sense in English.  What are typical numbers of edges E and vertices V in your graphs?  What are the max and min values for |V| and |E| ?  Do you have any bounds on number of neighbors of a vertex, or number of components?  Are all edges undirected?  Please answer by editing the question

Comment: Why do you want to parallelize the algorithm? You have many small instances, each of them will take only a short time. You can trivially run them in parallel, and the algorithm itself does not need to be parallel.

Comment: LAD might be just good enough for you: http://liris.cnrs.fr/csolnon/LAD.html It does not have anything special for super sparse graphs, though, but it is worth a try. On the website they have a link to the paper that discusses the algorithm, if you want to code it yourself.

Comment: To continue, I am guessing that running LAD will take not more that 1 hundredth of a second on such a small graph (in fact I think it'll be much faster). If this is true, then you need at most 11-12 days to run 10^8 graphs. So if you use 24 cores/processors, it'll be done within half a day.

Comment: @GaborCsardi, perhaps you want to turn your comment suggesting LAD into an answer, as you are suggesting an algorithm the way OP asked.

Comment: Are all of your pairwise testings comparing one fixed graph against a large set of possible isomorphic ones, or do you want to compare all pairs of a given set, or is there yet another source for these pairs? In the first case, putting some effort in analyzing that single reference graph might be worthwhile, whereas in the second case, clustering your set by some graph properties might prove a viable strategy to reduce the number of tests.

Comment: @MvG well it is the first case, but can you elaborate on what do you meant by "analyse the single reference graph".

Comment: @all I was reading on internet about NAUTY(http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/nauty/implement.shtml) and it looks good to me. Can anyone give their suggestions about using that in this project.

Comment: nauty is good, too, and BLISS as well (http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/). BLISS uses the same algorithm as nauty, but it is GPL, if that matters. I think basically any of these (LAD, nauty, BLISS) will work fine, and that most of the time will be spent reading the graph, scheduling the runs, etc, because these algorithms are all very fast on such small graphs.

Comment: You can also use some heuristics to rule out isomorphism quickly. E.g. the number of edges must be the same. The sorted degree sequence of the graph must match, too. If you cannot rule out a graph based on these two, you check explicitly for isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer relies on the fact that one of the two graphs will be the same for all of your isomorphism checks. There is a large variety of numbers you could compute for every node which are invariant under relabeling:

- The degree of the node
- The sum of the degrees of its neighbours
- The sum of the degrees of the neighbors of its neighbours
- For those neighbours with degree *k*, the sum of the degrees of their neighbours
- The number of loops of length *k* that contain this node
- The maximal distance from this node to any other node
- The number of nodes at distance *k* from this node
- …

You can take your reference graph and compute several of these numbers for every node. With a bit of luck, you'll find a set of functions which is not too costly to compute, and for which the resulting numbers will uniquely identify each node. You might even be able to hash these numbers down to a single number. In that case, you can process each input graph as follows: by computing these numbers and their hash for every node, you can quickly determine which node from the reference graph corresponds to each node of the input graph, if any. Once you have a one-to-one correspondence between nodes, checking whether all the edges fit is trivial.

If you don't find a cheap enough set of functions that uniquely describe *every* node, I would expect that in most real world graphs (i.e. not specifically constructed for high symmetry), you would still obtain rather small equivalence classes, so checking for all possible permutations in each class might still be cheap enough for your application.

Just as an idea: if performance is a real issue here, you might even try to turn the result of your analysis into customized program code. So for every reference graph, you'd have your application compile a small piece of code which it can then load dynamically to perform these checks with all the power that compiler-optimized machine code can give you. Not sure whether that's worth the effort, but I think it might be an interesting approach.

Highly symmetric graphs may require more work. You could try to identify isomorphisms of your graph up front. If, for example, you can interchange the labels of v1 and v2 without affecting the graph structure, then for every input graph you process, if you are unsure whether to map a given vertex to v1 or v2, you know that it doesn't matter, so you don't have to try both alternatives but can simply choose v1 arbitrarily. This greatly reducs the number of permutations you'll have to check.

Comment: I did not understood the following part of the answer "you might even try to turn the result of your analysis into customized program code". Can you please explain in some more detail.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: The idea is that you application may e.g. create some C code which does the computation. So instead of having objects that represent all the possible numbers you may compute, and pointers to functions with generic implementations of these functions, you might have a hard-coded piece of code that e.g. just computes the neighbours at distance 2 and 3, and aborts on the first indication of a mismatch. Such a specific implementation could be better optimized than the generic code. So your application would generate that C code and compile and load it automatically.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a way to quickly tell how many edges there are from v1 to v2 then you can quickly generate small representation of both graphs and do a brute force check. but if you can't quickly go through all your edges that means you can't even effectively read your input not talking about checking isomorphism